# Why am I getting drastically different results when using softmax instead of sigmoid in the output layer in CNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a simple model which classifies images of triangles and circles.

Code:

```
    model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150 ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'),])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(Xtr,ytr,epochs=3,batch_size=10)
```

The performance on the test set is:

[image]

But when I change the activation function in the output layer into `softmax`, i.e the last layer turns into `Dense(1,activation='softmax')`, the model's performance becomes

[image]

I made different dataset splits, the results remained roughly the same (the model with softmax activation performed equally badly). **What is the issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using softmax, with your current configuration, is actually forcing it to choose always only one class. It might be the reason you get always recall equal to zero for one class and one for the other class in your experience using softmax.

First, you need to change the loss. The `binary_crossentropy` is not supposed to be used for softmax. If you change the loss to `categorical cross-entropy` and make the DENSE of size 2 for the last layer( since you want to choose between two classes using softmax), you should get almost the same performance; i.e: change this part of the code;

```
Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'),])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with this one:

```
Dense(2,activation='softmax'),])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: You are right, loss was the issue. Although in my case `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` did the job (`categorical_crossentropy` threw error). Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: Great. Actually I think the difference is if you want the index of the one-hots or you want a list of probabs as the output of your model. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
model = Sequential([
Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150 ,3)),
MaxPooling2D(),
Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
MaxPooling2D(),
Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
MaxPooling2D(),
Flatten(),
Dense(512, activation='relu'),
#Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'),]) #this means you have 1 node in last layer
                                  #that's why you have result of 1 class
Dense(2,activation='softmax'),])  #this is meaninful for 2 class. it will work on your code
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(Xtr,ytr,epochs=3,batch_size=10)
```